# check boolean return value of mysql stored function in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm currently building the database for my system and wanted to create an abstraction of the db by using stored function and stored procedures for every request from php.
my question is i have a function that checks if an email exists and returns true if the email exist and false otherwise. now how can i check the Boolean return value after a pdo call in php. my php code is

```
$connection = new DB_CONNECTION(); 
$sql = "SELECT email_exists(:email) ";
$placeholder = array(":email" => $userMail );
$statement = $connection->prepare_query( $sql );
$result = $statement->execute($placeholder);
$result = $statement->fetch();
echo $result;
```

Comment: Array (size=1) "email_exists("the_email@give.com")" => '1') depending on the return 0 or 1

Comment: `$value = ($condition) ? TRUE : FALSE;` --- `$value = ($condition) ? 1 : 0;` --- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php - as per *"how can i check the Boolean return value"*.

Comment: Chris85 thank you i was looking for if thre was any cleaner way to get the result but this works fine to

Comment: Yeah i think the naming is better for readability too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the returned value an `alias` and it is accessible by that index in the array.

```
$connection = new DB_CONNECTION(); 
$sql = "SELECT email_exists(:email) as da_count ";
$placeholder = array(":email" => $userMail );
$statement = $connection->prepare_query( $sql );
$result = $statement->execute($placeholder);
$result = $statement->fetch();
echo $result['da_count'];
```

You can conditionalize that as needed;

```
if(empty($result['da_count'])) {
     echo 'Email doesnt exist';
} else {
     echo 'Email does exist';
}
```